# Using width="container" in an altair chart saved as html

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I am trying to use the feature `width="container"` that allows the width of the chart to be the same as parent container in a saved chart. The rendered chart does not use the width defined in the parent div. See the reprex below.

```
>>> import altair as alt
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from altair_saver import save
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...         {
...             "x": range(6),
...             "y": range(6, 0, -1),
...             "category": ["A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"],
...         }
...     )
...
>>> chart = alt.Chart(df, width="container").mark_line().encode(x="x:Q", y="y:Q", color="category:N")
>>> chart_html = save(chart, fmt="html", method="html", standalone=False)
>>> html = f"<html><head></head><body><div style='width: 500px'>{chart_html}</div></body></html>"
>>> with open("test_save.html", "w") as f:
...     f.write(html)
...
>>> alt.__version__
'4.1.0'
>>> from altair_saver import __version__
>>> __version__
'0.5.0'
```

The rendered chart is very small, and if I change the size of the window in any way, the chart grows.[image]

Maybe there is something I do not understand or use incorrectly. I want the chart rendered as HTML as I am not in a notebook environment.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Vega-Lite. I'd suggest reporting it at http://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues

Comment: Done [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6616)